# Incorrect Syntax Error Near the word ON

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep getting an incorrect syntax near the word ON, this code is from a suggested change from a previous post and I am trying to find where the error is and so far I am having no luck figuring out what punctuation mark I am missing. The code is

```
SELECT AC.REG_NR, AC.DIS_NR, AC.GEMSID, AC.TMS_ID, AC.EMP_NA, AC.EMP_SEX_TYP_CD, AC.EMP_EOC_GRP_TYP_CD, AC.DIV_NR, AC.CTR_NR, 
           AC.JOB_CLS_CD_DSC_TE, AC.JOB_GRP_CD, AC.Job_Function, AC.Job_Group, AC.Meeting_Readiness_Rating, AC.Manager_Readiness_Rating, CD.Employee_ID, 
           CD.Meeting_Readiness_Rating AS Expr1, CD.Manager_Readiness_Rating AS Expr2, CD.Meeting_End_Date, CD.EmployeeFeedback, 
           CD.DevelopmentForEmployee1, CD.DevelopmentForEmployee2, CD.DevelopmentForEmployee3, CD.DevelopmentForEmployee4, CD.DevelopmentForEmployee5, 
           CD.Justification, CD.Changed, CD.Notes
FROM  dbo.AC_Source AS AC INNER JOIN
(SELECT EmployeeID AS Employee_ID, MeetingReadinessLevel AS Meeting_Readiness_Rating, ManagerReadinessLevel AS Manager_Readiness_Rating, 
                               logdate AS Meeting_End_Date, EmployeeFeedback, DevelopmentForEmployee1, DevelopmentForEmployee2, DevelopmentForEmployee3, 
                               DevelopmentForEmployee4, DevelopmentForEmployee5, Justification, Changed, Notes
FROM (SELECT EmployeeID AS Employee_ID, MeetingReadinessLevel AS Meeting_Readiness_Rating, ManagerReadinessLevel AS Manager_Readiness_Rating, 
                               logdate AS Meeting_End_Date, EmployeeFeedback, DevelopmentForEmployee1, DevelopmentForEmployee2, DevelopmentForEmployee3, 
                               DevelopmentForEmployee4, DevelopmentForEmployee5, Justification, Changed, Notes, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY Meeting_End_Date DESC) As RowNum
FROM (SELECT EmployeeID AS Employee_ID, MeetingReadinessLevel AS Meeting_Readiness_Rating, ManagerReadinessLevel AS Manager_Readiness_Rating, 
                               logdate AS Meeting_End_Date, EmployeeFeedback, DevelopmentForEmployee1, DevelopmentForEmployee2, DevelopmentForEmployee3, 
                               DevelopmentForEmployee4, DevelopmentForEmployee5, Justification, Changed, Notes
                FROM   dbo.AC_CDData_1
                UNION ALL
                SELECT Employee_ID, Meeting_Readiness_Rating, Manager_Readiness_Rating, Meeting_End_Date, '' AS EmployeeFeedback, '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee1, 
                               '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee2, '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee3, '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee4, '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee5, '' AS Justification, 
                               '' AS Changed, '' AS Notes
                FROM  dbo.TMS_Data_Latest_Career_Meeting_Rating
                WHERE (Plan_Year = '2013')) AS InnerSelect) AS CD ON AC.TMS_ID = CD.Employee_ID
WHERE RowNum = 1)
ON AC.TMS_ID = CD.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

Comment: `WHERE RowNum = 1) ON AC.TMS_ID = CD.EMPLOYEE_ID;` looks like the subquery's alias is missing after the closing `)`. This is too dense for me to visually figure out which alias that should be (`AC`, or `CD`) without analysis but you are probably looking for `WHERE RowNum = 1) AS CD ON AC.TMS_ID = CD.EMPLOYEE_ID;`

Comment: I tried that and still getting the error

Comment: Learn CTE(Common Table Expression). If you do this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something wrong with this query (ok, nothing new..). There is no alias on the final subquery, but it seems there's more.

The simplified and properly indented form might help you spotting the problem:

```
SELECT x
FROM  dbo.AC_Source AS AC 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT x
    FROM (
        SELECT x, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY Meeting_End_Date DESC) As RowNum
        FROM (
            SELECT x
            FROM   dbo.AC_CDData_1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT x
            FROM  dbo.TMS_Data_Latest_Career_Meeting_Rating
            WHERE Plan_Year = '2013'
        ) AS InnerSelect
    ) AS CD ON AC.TMS_ID = CD.Employee_ID
    WHERE RowNum = 1
) ON AC.TMS_ID = CD.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, all subqueries need an alias.  So, give the subqueries a name.  I think it is something like this:

```
SELECT AC.REG_NR, AC.DIS_NR, AC.GEMSID, AC.TMS_ID, AC.EMP_NA, AC.EMP_SEX_TYP_CD,
       AC.EMP_EOC_GRP_TYP_CD, AC.DIV_NR, AC.CTR_NR, 
       AC.JOB_CLS_CD_DSC_TE, AC.JOB_GRP_CD, AC.Job_Function, AC.Job_Group,
       AC.Meeting_Readiness_Rating, AC.Manager_Readiness_Rating, CD.Employee_ID, 
       CD.Meeting_Readiness_Rating AS Expr1, CD.Manager_Readiness_Rating AS Expr2, 
       CD.Meeting_End_Date, CD.EmployeeFeedback, 
       CD.DevelopmentForEmployee1, CD.DevelopmentForEmployee2, CD.DevelopmentForEmployee3, 
       CD.DevelopmentForEmployee4, CD.DevelopmentForEmployee5, 
       CD.Justification, CD.Changed, CD.Notes
FROM  dbo.AC_Source AS AC INNER JOIN
       (SELECT EmployeeID AS Employee_ID, MeetingReadinessLevel AS Meeting_Readiness_Rating, ManagerReadinessLevel AS Manager_Readiness_Rating, 
                               logdate AS Meeting_End_Date, EmployeeFeedback, DevelopmentForEmployee1, DevelopmentForEmployee2, DevelopmentForEmployee3, 
                               DevelopmentForEmployee4, DevelopmentForEmployee5, Justification, Changed, Notes
FROM (SELECT EmployeeID AS Employee_ID, MeetingReadinessLevel AS Meeting_Readiness_Rating,
             ManagerReadinessLevel AS Manager_Readiness_Rating, 
             logdate AS Meeting_End_Date, EmployeeFeedback, DevelopmentForEmployee1, 
             DevelopmentForEmployee2, DevelopmentForEmployee3, 
             DevelopmentForEmployee4, DevelopmentForEmployee5, Justification, Changed, 
             Notes,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY Meeting_End_Date DESC) As RowNum
      FROM (SELECT EmployeeID AS Employee_ID, MeetingReadinessLevel AS Meeting_Readiness_Rating, ManagerReadinessLevel AS Manager_Readiness_Rating, 
                               logdate AS Meeting_End_Date, EmployeeFeedback, DevelopmentForEmployee1, DevelopmentForEmployee2, DevelopmentForEmployee3, 
                               DevelopmentForEmployee4, DevelopmentForEmployee5, Justification, Changed, Notes
            FROM   dbo.AC_CDData_1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT Employee_ID, Meeting_Readiness_Rating, Manager_Readiness_Rating, Meeting_End_Date, '' AS EmployeeFeedback, '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee1, 
                               '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee2, '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee3, '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee4, '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee5, '' AS Justification, 
                               '' AS Changed, '' AS Notes
            FROM  dbo.TMS_Data_Latest_Career_Meeting_Rating
            WHERE (Plan_Year = '2013')) AS InnerSelect
          ) cd
     ) cd
     ON AC.TMS_ID = CD.EMPLOYEE_ID and rownum = 1
```

Comment: THat does not work either, it gives me errors for all the fields

Answer (score 0):

This is how your query should have looked like. If you use CTE it is easy to read and easy to find errors.

Documentation on CTE http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

```
    ;WITH   Query1
          AS (
               SELECT EmployeeID AS Employee_ID
                   ,MeetingReadinessLevel AS Meeting_Readiness_Rating
                   ,ManagerReadinessLevel AS Manager_Readiness_Rating
                   ,logdate AS Meeting_End_Date
                   ,EmployeeFeedback
                   ,DevelopmentForEmployee1
                   ,DevelopmentForEmployee2
                   ,DevelopmentForEmployee3
                   ,DevelopmentForEmployee4
                   ,DevelopmentForEmployee5
                   ,Justification
                   ,Changed
                   ,Notes
                FROM dbo.AC_CDData_1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT Employee_ID
                   ,Meeting_Readiness_Rating
                   ,Manager_Readiness_Rating
                   ,Meeting_End_Date
                   ,'' AS EmployeeFeedback
                   ,'' AS DevelopmentForEmployee1
                   ,'' AS DevelopmentForEmployee2
                   ,'' AS DevelopmentForEmployee3
                   ,'' AS DevelopmentForEmployee4
                   ,'' AS DevelopmentForEmployee5
                   ,'' AS Justification
                   ,'' AS Changed
                   ,'' AS Notes
                FROM dbo.TMS_Data_Latest_Career_Meeting_Rating
                WHERE Plan_Year = '2013'
             ),
        Query2
          AS (
               SELECT Employee_ID
                   ,Meeting_Readiness_Rating
                   ,Manager_Readiness_Rating
                   ,Meeting_End_Date
                   ,EmployeeFeedback
                   ,DevelopmentForEmployee1
                   ,DevelopmentForEmployee2
                   ,DevelopmentForEmployee3
                   ,DevelopmentForEmployee4
                   ,DevelopmentForEmployee5
                   ,Justification
                   ,Changed
                   ,Notes
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Employee_ID ORDER BY Meeting_End_Date DESC ) AS Rn
                FROM Query1 AS q1
             )
    SELECT AC.REG_NR
           ,AC.DIS_NR
           ,AC.GEMSID
           ,AC.TMS_ID
           ,AC.EMP_NA
           ,AC.EMP_SEX_TYP_CD
           ,AC.EMP_EOC_GRP_TYP_CD
           ,AC.DIV_NR
           ,AC.CTR_NR
           ,AC.JOB_CLS_CD_DSC_TE
           ,AC.JOB_GRP_CD
           ,AC.Job_Function
           ,AC.Job_Group
           ,AC.Meeting_Readiness_Rating
           ,AC.Manager_Readiness_Rating
           ,CD.Employee_ID
           ,CD.Meeting_Readiness_Rating AS Expr1
           ,CD.Manager_Readiness_Rating AS Expr2
           ,CD.Meeting_End_Date
           ,CD.EmployeeFeedback
           ,CD.DevelopmentForEmployee1
           ,CD.DevelopmentForEmployee2
           ,CD.DevelopmentForEmployee3
           ,CD.DevelopmentForEmployee4
           ,CD.DevelopmentForEmployee5
           ,CD.Justification
           ,CD.Changed
           ,CD.Notes
        FROM dbo.AC_Source AS AC
        INNER JOIN Query2 AS cd
            ON AC.TMS_ID = CD.EMPLOYEE_ID
               AND cd.rn = 1
```